# Sub expression that returns a value

Tags: c#

In [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), there is the following example:

```
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine (line);
   counter++;
}
```

I'm still learning C#, coming from a background in VB.  My question is: in what circumstances can you use one of these "sub expressions", e.g. `(line = file.ReadLine())`, what is that actually called (I know it's probably not "sub expression"), and how do you know if and what it returns (I'm assuming in this case it returns whatever value is assigned to `line`)?

Comment: assignments happen right to left....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it returns the value as specified in the specification in [`7.13.1 Simple assignment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691315(v=vs.71).aspx):

> The result of a simple assignment expression is the value assigned to the left operand.

You can use them wherever you want and/or wherever you think they might be useful as in the example in your question.

Answer (score 2):

> The result of a simple assignment expression is the value assigned to
>   the left operand. The result has the same type as the left operand and
>   is always classified as a value.

Therefore, the result of the `line = file.ReadLine()` expression is the value (in this case the line of text) assigned to the `line` variable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691315(v=vs.71).aspx